# Laravel Eloquent Distant Relationship Setup

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables, a user table, documents table, and a favourites table. The idea is a user can favourite a document, but I can't understand the best way to query this using Eloquent.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Document');
    }

    public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Favourite');
    }
}
```

**Document.php**

```
class Document extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Favourite.php**

```
class Favourite extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function document()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Document');
    }

}
```

The favourite table is a simple 2 column table with the user_id and the document_id linking each user to an article they have favourited.

Now I can use a method to get the users favourite articles like so:

```
App\User::with('favourites')->find(1);
```

The problem is this brings back the two id's from the favourites table when I want the data from the documents table such as the title and id of the document.

It looks like the "has-many-through" relationship is what I might need to achieve this query, but I'm unsure how to implement it in this use case or even if the "has-many-through" relationship is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please give feedback on the answers.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I'm yet to implement this project as the deadline has been pushed back, they all look like valid options so it's down to a matter of opinion on which is the best implementation. I don't want to give my personal opinion until I have tried the options.

Answer (score 0):

As your relationship is being setup, you can have a user that has multiple documents, and he can also make multiple documents to be his favorites. So it will always return an array. In order to load all the documents for the user that are his favorites, you can do that the same as you started:

```
$favoriteDocuments = App\User::with('favourites.document')->find($userId = 1)->get();

// this will contain all the favorite documents for the user, so you can the iterate over them:

foreach($favoriteDocuments as $favoriteDocument)
{
    // $favoriteDocument->document; is the object you are looking for.
}
```

Has many through relationship is used in order to get item from a table to which you don't have access to directly. But to both of your tables you have direct connection to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with has-many-through, so on User:

```php
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Document', 'App\Favourite');
```

And on Document:

```php
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Favourite');
```

[Eloquent Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

Your favorites table is a Pivot table. You don't need a favorites model.

```
User.php

public function favoriteDocuments()
{
    return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Document', 'favorite_documents');
}
```

Now you can call `$user->favoriteDocuments` to get the users documents.

See the docs about many to many relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many.